# Is there a maximum recommended amount of replicas for a Clickhouse table?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree table on a cluster on version 20.3.9 (I know it is old, sorry).

This cluster serves a relatively high volume of cheap queries. So it seems I can scale this solution for a while by adding replicas as one node can easily serve each query in a reasonable time.
What are the limits here assuming no issues with increased write volume or increased dataset size. I understand that the limiting factors would be:

- network bandwidth for replication, which totally depends on the infrastructure.
- zookeeper.

Is there a maximum recommended number of replicas Zookeeper can handle for a shard? And is this going to change with the Zookeeper replacement?

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a maximum recommended number of replicas Zookeeper can handle for a shard?

No maximum.
From my experience I know that people used 10 replicas (fact tables) without any issues. And 75 replica for dimensions (small) tables.

> And is this going to change with the Zookeeper replacement?

No changes.